# VB.Net override a property

Tags: vb.net, properties, overriding

I need to override this property so that I can return a calculated value. I am not throwing any errors but it is not working. What am I doing wrong? Any help would be great.

This is in the base class. BalanceValue is a private decimal.

```
Public Overridable Property Balance() As Decimal

    Get
        Return balanceValue
    End Get

    Set(balance As Decimal)
        If balance >= 0D Then
            balanceValue = balance
        Else
            Throw New ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Balance must be greater than or equal to 0")
        End If
    End Set

End Property
```

This is in the derived class.

```
Public Overrides Property Balance() As Decimal
    Get
        Return CDec(BalanceWithInterest)
    End Get

    Set(balance As Decimal)
        MyBase.Balance = CDec(BalanceWithInterest)
    End Set
End Property
```

This is what I want it to return

```
 Public Function CalculateInterest(interestRate As Double) As Decimal

    Return CDec(MyBase.Balance + (MyBase.Balance * interestRate))

End Function
```

Comment: Your CalculateInterest function is intentionally not using the overridden property for some unguessable reason.  Use Me.Balance instead of MyBase.Balance.

Comment: I did that and it still isnt working. I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Since you are returning BalanceWithInterest, you should probably be setting it:  `BalanceWithInterest = balance`

Comment: _still isn't working_ is not a very good problem description.  _How_ is it not working?  What results do you expect and what results do you actually see?  Show the code that calls `CalculateInterest`.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not totally sure what you're looking for, but maybe try this code. I'm using the `Shadows` instead of `Overrides` keyword because the parameters of the property are different in the derived class than the parent class.

```
  Public Shadows Property Balance(interestRate As Double) As Decimal
    Get
      Return CDec(MyBase.Balance + (MyBase.Balance * interestRate))
    End Get
    Set(balance As Decimal)
      MyBase.Balance = CDec(balance / (1 + interestRate))
    End Set
  End Property
```

Comment: If you are using Attributes on your properties, Shadows clears them out while Overrides doesn't.